# In python using while loop calculate circumference and area

Tags: python

Write a program that will calculate the circumference and surface area of a circle. Create a table that prints the circumference and surface area for a radius from 1cm to 20 cm inclusive in increments of .5 cm.

I've tried this

```
import math

def main():

    # inputs
    radius = int(20)
    i = float
    # loop
    while i in range(1, radius+1):
        a = math.pi * radius ** 2
        c = 2 * math.pi * radius
        print(f'{i:3d}{a:13.2f}{c:15.2f}')

        break
main()
```

But nothing happens when I run the program.

Comment: `break` breaks out of the loop. If you're planning to break unconditionally, you don't need a loop.

Comment: nothing happens because you set `i` as a reference to the `float` function, so the `while` statement starts out being false and never executes.  Did you mean for it to be a `for` loop instead of a `while`?

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize `radius` as 1 and loop until it is greater than 20, incrementing it by `0.5` at the end of each iteration.

```
def main():
    radius = 1
    while radius <= 20:
        a = math.pi * radius ** 2
        c = 2 * math.pi * radius
        print(f'{a:13.2f}{c:15.2f}')
        radius += .5
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from numpy import pi
from numpy import arange

def main():
    # Python makes it easy to directly loop over different radius values
    # no need to manually check conditions (tip: have a look at iterators)
    for radius in arange(0.5, 20.0, 0.5): 
        # directly assigns value to radius
        # instead of the OPs checking of i in the while loop. No need for i at all
        a = pi * radius**2
        c = 2 * pi * radius
        print(f'{radius}{a:13.2f}{c:15.2f}')
        # no need for "break"

main() # call to function
```

Comment: May you add more information to explain your approach and what make the OP didn't work. It is must more helpful to understand the underline problem than copy/paste a working code while not sure why it work